# Power BI & Spark - ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (4)

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi, thrift, azure-hdinsight, spark-thriftserver

I am connecting Power BI to Spark but getting this error after attempting connection:

> Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (4) Error occurred while contacting server: SSL_read: error code: 0. The connection has been configured to not use SASL for authentication. This error might be due to the server has been configured to use SASL for authentication.
>   ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (4) Error occurred while contacting server: SSL_read: error code: 0. The connection has been configured to not use SASL for authentication. This error might be due to the server has been configured to use SASL for authentication."

I have tried the following:

1. Reinstall PBI desktop -64bit
2. Installed Microsoft ODBC spark driver

Answer (score 0):

We also received this error.  After investigation, I found that this was due to a downstream server involved in user authentication being unreachable.

Therefore re-installation of client software like Power BI is not likely to remedy this situation.